# Qlikview: change color of second Dimension

Tags: colors, qlikview

I have a Qlikview graph in which I have 2 dimensions. I now want to know if it is possible to recolor the text of that second dimension.

See image for clarification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryANA.jpg (the CPU core text on the right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's property of the legend.

Right click on the chart --> Properties --> Presentation --> (Legend group on top right) --> Settings --> Font and from there you can change font size/name/color.